# When to seperate database column meaning (generic columns)

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm designing a feedback system for a site which has approximately 20 questions, but those questions may change each year and trying to consider the best design.

The simplest way is to map each question into a column, but this would require creating a new table each year and changing the application code which isn't sensible at all.

The second option is to separate the columns from the meaning and have a second table that applies meaning, i.e.

```
Table1: (row per survey)  Table2: (row per questionnaire type)
QuestionID                AnswerID
Question1                 QuestionID
Question2                 Answer1
...                       ....  
Question20                Answer20
```

The third option I can think of is to completely separate each aspect like:

```
Table1:       Table2:     Table3:       Table4:
QuestionID    AnswerID    MatchTableID  SetID
QuestionValue AnswerValue QuestionID    FeedbackSet
                          AnswerID      QuestionID
```

Which gives it the benefit of scalability, but it may be excessive for something changing at most once a year for a few hundred records and i'm not sure if that doesn't feel a bit too much like an Entity-Attribute-Value design.

I'd appreciate any comments on what is considered to be best practice here and what is considered acceptable practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to just keep it simple and go with a classic relational setup.

The models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replies
  has_many :answers
  belongs_to :questionnaire
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :replies
end

# A collection of questions
class Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :replies, through: :questions
end

# A user reply to a question
# acts as a many to many join table
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

The schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160215124045) do

  create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "text"
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "answers", ["question_id"], name: "index_answers_on_question_id"

  create_table "questionnaires", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "text"
    t.integer  "questionnaire_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end

  add_index "questions", ["questionnaire_id"], name: "index_questions_on_questionnaire_id"

  create_table "replies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.integer  "answer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "replies", ["answer_id"], name: "index_replies_on_answer_id"
  add_index "replies", ["question_id"], name: "index_replies_on_question_id"

end
```

Yeah its a lot of tables - but this gives you a great deal of flexibility without dealing with the hassle that is key value tables. And its also much faster to build than some hacky attempt at a dynamic schema.

Its also really easy to pull out metrics if needed.

This example makes quite a few assumptions:

- The questions are multiple choice - not write in. You can quite simply adapt it by storing the write-ins on the replies table.
- The relation between question and questionnaire is one-to-one. Use a join table and HABTM relationship or `has_many through:` if need to be able to reuse questions on multiple questionnaires.

Comment: Interesting answer, thank you. I understand from the syntax this is rails? Whats the HAB in HABMTM? The questions are a mix of free text, multiple choice and integers.

Comment: For the record i'm using mssql, since it was a question about design methodology i tried to keep it as generic as possible.

Comment: I mistakenly though it was tagged Rails, so yes this is a Rails example. However I would build the database structure about the same irregardless of the framework.

Comment: Has And Belongs To Many (HABTM) - I always end up getting that one wrong. Its one way of defining a many to many relationship in Rails.

Comment: For a mix of free text, multiple choice and integers, you could just store a type on the answers table. So for a "freetext only" question you just add a answer with the type freetext. this lets you mix and match however you want for a question.

Comment: That's great, I can infer the differences thanks, but i'm not sure what is the logic behind why you'd use an 'empty' table with a many to many lookup table as opposed to having it as an FK to question in questionnaire?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean